# python pandas tabulate not printing least significant digit when zero

Tags: python, pandas

I'm printing a dataframe using tabulate which contains a cost field but the least significant digit is blank when it's zero.

I suspect the issue is related to floating point vs decimal numbers but nothing I've tried has worked.

I'm not sure what the correct way to format the decimal output is.
The map parameter below suggests floating point; can I convert to decimal?

Here's the relevant lines of code and the output:

```
lists['Cost_Items'] = lists['Cost_Items'].map('{0:,.2f}'.format)

print(tabulate(lists, headers='keys', tablefmt='pipe', numalign='decimal', showindex=False))

    | Item     | Date_Purchased   |   Cost_Items |
    |:---------|:-----------------|-------------:|
    | Item 1   | 2018-03-31       |        10.64 |
    | Item 2   | 2018-03-31       |         2.48 |
    | Item 3   | 2018-03-31       |         3.1  |
    | Item 4   | 2018-03-31       |         1.78 |
    | Item 5   | 2018-03-31       |         2.93 |
    | Item 6   | 2018-03-31       |         0.5  |
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need `floatfmt` parameter, check [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate):

```
print(tabulate(lists, headers='keys', tablefmt='pipe', floatfmt=".2f", showindex=False))
| Item   | Date_Purchased   |   Cost_Items |
|:-------|:-----------------|-------------:|
| Item 1 | 2018-03-31       |        10.64 |
| Item 2 | 2018-03-31       |         2.48 |
| Item 3 | 2018-03-31       |         3.10 |
| Item 4 | 2018-03-31       |         1.78 |
| Item 5 | 2018-03-31       |         2.93 |
| Item 6 | 2018-03-31       |         0.50 |
```

---

```
print(tabulate(lists, headers='keys', tablefmt='pipe', floatfmt=".3f", showindex=False))
| Item   | Date_Purchased   |   Cost_Items |
|:-------|:-----------------|-------------:|
| Item 1 | 2018-03-31       |       10.640 |
| Item 2 | 2018-03-31       |        2.480 |
| Item 3 | 2018-03-31       |        3.100 |
| Item 4 | 2018-03-31       |        1.780 |
| Item 5 | 2018-03-31       |        2.930 |
| Item 6 | 2018-03-31       |        0.500 |
```